# Sending a file from server side to client side using TCP in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

Now this is a bit more of a request since I am not able to find 
any simple and direct example for this.

Issue: I want to send a file from the server side to the client side.

When the server is already up and listening on a port and the client requests a file (file's name being accepted as a parameter with the server IP address such as 127.0.0.1 and port no.)
and then the process of transfer starts till the file is copied.

Also can someone incorporate how can i measure the average transfer speed on the server side?

BTW: I am running Linux x86
Cheers,
echo9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check **[Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)**. There are lots of examples there that shows how to implement a client/server architecture using sockets and send data between them.

**EDIT**:

Check items 8 and 9 from [this tutorial](http://binarii.com/files/papers/c_sockets.txt) for a complete example on client/server. Note that on item 8, the server sends a `char*` to the client:

```
send(fd2,"Welcome to my server.\n",22,0); /* send to the client welcome message */
```

On this case, it's the `"Welcome to my server.\n"` string, and the next parameter is the size of the string you want to send.

When you need to send data from a file it's the same thing: first, you need to read the data from the file and store it in a `char* buffer;` that you manually allocated through *malloc()*.

Something like this:

```
char* buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc(1024); // let's say your file has 1KB of data

/* insert here the code to read data from the file and populate buffer with it */

send(fd2, buffer, 1024,0);
```

Comment: @echo9 How can Beej's Guide not be helpful? It describes everything you need to know about sockets. Please describe how far you got with your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple protocol:

```
CLIENT                   SERVER
                         socket(), bind(), listen()
socket(), connect()
                         accept()
send("GET filename\n")
                         recv(buffer)
                         inspect buffer, parse filename (stop at space or \n),
                         open() file.
                         sendfile(file, socket)
                         close(socket)
                         close(file)
 recv(socket)
 close()
```

This protocol has the advantage of being able to use your web browser as the client, and your web server as the host, assuming they each support [HTTP/0.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html).

[Here's a client](http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/19/Web_Client.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [sendfile(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html).